# saving documents in rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model, "Grievance". A grievance can have many documents attached to it. Documents can be associated with all kinds of things so they are polymorphic.

Here is the grievance model

```
class Grievance < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :account
  belongs_to :employee

  has_many :documents, :class_name => "EmployeeDocument", :as => 'documentable'
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :documents, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

the show page of a grievance allows the user to upload multiple documents to be associated with the grievance. This works really well.

I am refactoring the code of another developer, and looking at the update action in the controller. His code looks like this...

```
def update
  @grievance = @employee.grievances.find(params[:id])

  update! {
    flash[:notice] = 'Updated successfully'
    redirect_to edit_employee_grievance_path(:employee_id => @employee.id, :id => @grievance, :tab_to_return_to => params[:tab_to_return_to]) and return }
  render :form
end
```

Whilst this works fine, I wanted to refactor it, basically to make it more readable as I learn. So I changed it to this.

```
def update
  @grievance = @employee.grievances.find(params[:id])

  if @grievance.save
    flash[:notice] = "#{@grievance.grievance_type} record updated"
    redirect_to employee_grievance_path(@employee, @grievance) and return
  else
    flash[:alert] = "There was a problem editing the record"
    render :edit
  end
```

Now I appreciate his code is more advanced than more, and certainly more concise, but what I am trying to understand is why does his code successfully save the documents, and mine does not. I can see in the log that the form is passing the details of the document back to the controller, so it must be something to do with the update code?

Comment: You ask if it has been saved, but are you ever actually saving?

Comment: I think it would also be safe to remove the `and return` in your code since that is usually only needed to prevent the double render or redirect error. In your version that is taken care of by the if/else statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your version, there is nothing being done to the `@greivance` between being loaded, and saved.

You are missing something like this:

```
@grievance.update_attributes(params[:grievance])
```

Inside those params are attributes from the form that set the values of `@grievance`, as well as it's nested attributes to save the attached documents.

The other developer's version is using [Inherited Resources](https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources), which does all that automatically. They are just overriding the functionality that is different from the InheritedResources default.